# Is it possible for the trackpad to behave like a trackball with intertial physics?

Tags: trackpad, macos

It would be neat if in trackpad settings there were a setting for this. So, if you start the pointer moving and take your finder off the trackpad, the cursor would slowly stop using the exact same curve as window scrolling.

You can set this for two finger scrolling, but not for the pointer. I'm sure many think this is crazy, but having been a trackball user for years, I think it would be excellent. Is this possible? Maybe via 3rd party tools?